# How to set powershell to send email alerts when returned JSON api is empty

Tags: json, api, powershell, email

i need to write a powershell script to connect to a REST API and to output into a text file stored locally. How do i write it such that if the REST API has issues and timeout without returning a response, the powershell script will trigger an email to send out when the saved text file is empty? 
Also, how do i append the date to the saved text file for eg. c:\scripts\response_DDMMYYYY.txt

Below are my current powershell script. Newbie at powershell scripting. Hope someone can enlighten me. 
Thanks alot!

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object 
TrustAllCertsPolicy

$url = "https://someapi.com/get_info"
$token = '12345'

$header = @{Authorization = "Bearer $token" }
$body = @{code = "ABC"}

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $url -ContentType 
'application/json' -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body) -Header $header 

$result | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Set-Content "c:\scripts\response.txt"
```

Edited based on kumar's advice:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
    public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
         }
    }
 "@
 [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object 
 TrustAllCertsPolicy

 $url = "https://someapi.com/get_info"

 $token = '12345'

 $header = @{Authorization = "Bearer $token" }
 $body = @{code = "ABC"}

 try {
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $url -ContentType 
    'application/json' -Body (ConvertTo-Json $body) -Header $header 

    $time = (Get-Date).ToString("DD-MM-YYYY")
    $result | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Set-Content "c:\scripts\response- 
    "+$time+".txt"

 } catch {
     Write-Host "StatusCode: " $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
     Write-Host "StatusDescription:" 
 $_.Exception.Response.Status.StatusDescription

     Send-MailMessage -To "ABC<abc@gmail.com>" -From "server <admin@abc.com>" 
 -Subject "Error with sync to server"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to get the response status code of the REST call like so..

```
try {
    Invoke-RestMethod ... your parameters here ... 
} catch {
    # Dig into the exception to get the Response details.
    # Note that value__ is not a typo.
    Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
    Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
}
```

& Use the [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1)

```
Send-MailMessage -To "User01 <user01@example.com>" -From "User02 <user02@example.com>" -Subject "Test mail"
```

> Also, how do i append the date to the saved text file for eg. c:\scripts\response_DDMMYYYY.txt

A simple and nice way is:

```
$time = (Get-Date).ToString("DD-MM-YYYY")
```

and simply

```
("C:\scripts\response-"+$time+".txt")
```

Comment: Thanks Pawan kumar! i edited my codes and retest. Is this correct? Let me try to post it here.

Comment: i receive the error Send-MailMessage : The email cannot be sent because no SMTP server was specified. You must specify an SMTP server by using either the SmtpServer parameter or the $PSEmailServer 
variable.

Comment: StatusCode and StatusDescription returns empty too. Am i supposed to add anything?

Comment: Inorder to use send-mailmessage , you should have a set SMTP server variable like `$PSEmailServer = "ho-ex2010-caht1.exchangeserverpro.net"`. Here is a link that explains how to get it working via powershell [link]https://practical365.com/exchange-server/powershell-how-to-send-email/

Comment: Set-Content : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match 
any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

Comment: i made some changes, all is working now. Thanks kumar!